# Older/Previous Posts on Wordpress with Categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having some major problems getting my older/newer posts working on Wordpress when only showing 1 category's posts on a page.

It worked absolutely fine before I was defining a category, but now my client wants one category on one page, and another category on another.

The code that I'm using is pasted below. If you'd like a temporary login, I can set you up.. this has been driving me crazy for the past 2 hours!

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query($querystring . 'cat=3&posts_per_page=8');
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>

<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>


                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>


        <div class="post"  id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">     
                    <h2 class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></h2></div>

            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry'); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages('<p><strong>Pages:</strong> ', '</p>', 'number'); ?>

                                </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: You have hidden what `$querystring` contains. Also the code about the loop part is mainly boilerplate, you can shorten it by just leaving some `...` because it's just the standard output. This might improve your question, so you might get better answers. Consider editing it. Also it's always good to peek into the manual: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this corrected version. You have to use query_posts to work with $querystring, not WP_Query (because it is not new, it is using the same one, complementing its querystring with other parameters):

```
<?php query_posts($querystring . 'cat=-123&posts_per_page=8');
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>

<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>


            <?php get_template_part( 'content' ); ?>


    <div class="post"  id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">     
                <h2 class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></h2></div>

        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry'); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages('<p><strong>Pages:</strong> ', '</p>', 'number'); ?>

                            </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm afraid this still doesn't work. It shows me the posts from the correct category, but when I click "Older Posts" it just shows me the same page, however the URL shows /page/2. Any ideas? The code I'm using for the older/newer posts is:

 ` <div id="posts-nav">
    <div id="next-posts">
     <?php next_posts_link('<< Older Entries', 0); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="prev-posts">
     <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries >>', 0) ?>
    </div>
   </div>  `

Comment: You have to add a parameter in query_posts :  `'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )` so the pagination is taken into account when executing the loop on subsequent pages

Answer (score 0):

Thanks your your help. I've managed to get it working using the WP Posts Filter plugin. Not perfect, but a workaround which does what I need it to.